# how to implement pdf editor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf

I am working on an application and I am using `pdfkit` which I should have the ability to read pdf files and edit them. I found that iOS has an editor like the image below it self 
    [image]

is there any way to implement something like this one in my application? what should I searched for?

Appreciate any help. thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
func createAndEditPDF() {

        let pdfURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.selectedFile.fileURL); // URL of the existing PDF 
        if let pdf:CGPDFDocument = CGPDFDocument(pdfURL as CFURL) { // Create a PDF Document
            let _newURL = "\(documentFolderPath)/\(self.selectedFile.name)"; // New URL to save editable PDF
            let _url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: _newURL)
            var _mediaBox:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight); // mediabox which will set the height and width of page
            let _writeContext = CGContext(_url, mediaBox: &_mediaBox, nil) // get the context

            //Run a loop to the number of pages you want
            for i in 0..<self.pages.count
            {
                if let _page = pdf.page(at: self.pages[i]) { // get the page number
                    var _pageRect:CGRect = page.getBoxRect(CGPDFBox.mediaBox) // get the page rect 
                    _writeContext!.beginPage(mediaBox: &_pageRect); // begin new page with given page rect
                    _writeContext!.drawPDFPage(_page); // draw content in page
                    _writeContext!.endPage(); // end the current page
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you it seems fine but I should work more on it. I will let you know if further problem exists. thank you very much

Comment: Happy Coding :-)

Comment: what should be value of pageWidth and pageHeight?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question

Comment: @fullMoon you get the answer?