# How to amend select fields in document or PDF using SWIFT

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3, swift2, mobile-application

Is there any way I can have a document or PDF stored on my swift application file and edit select predefined fields inside the document/pdf using swift code?

For example the document/pdf would contain the following fields i'd like to amend; [INPUT1], [INPUT2], [INPUT3]

- "What is [INPUT1] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the [INPUT2], when an unknown printer
  took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type [INPUT3] book.
  It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
  electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."

In swift I would like to ask the user 3 questions and have their answers replace [INPUT1], [INPUT2], [INPUT3] respectively.

If not possible to edit word/pdf file is there any other way to achieve this while being able to keep the formatting of the text mentioned above while only changing the mentioned fields.

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Look into implementing PDFKit and see this answer [how to implement pdf editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764990/how-to-implement-pdf-editor)

You have: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit

Comment: This would work if it was visual changes but I am not sure how I can edit the text itself that's contained in the word document/pdf